# How to remove iframe after printing?

Tags: javascript

```js
export const printPdf = (data: any) => {
  const newBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
  const fileLink = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob)
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.src = fileLink
  iframe.id = 'print_pdf'
  iframe.name = 'print_pdf'
  // iframe.setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
  iframe.onload = () => {
    iframe.contentWindow!.onafterprint = () => {
      document.body.removeChild(iframe)
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)
  window.frames['print_pdf'].focus()
  window.frames['print_pdf'].print()
  window.frames['print_pdf'].onafterprint = () =>
    document.body.removeChild(iframe)
}
```

I tried everything that I've found. And still, after printing iframe window doesn't have this event listener so nothing is called.

Comment: @CodeF0x My assumption is, OP is using Typescript and that is a Bang operator

Comment: @CodeF0x its typescript. So it basically means an iframe object 100% will have `contentWindow` property. Cause if I call it for example before `onload` listener it throws that object doesn't have this property

Comment: Minor question. Why are you registering event after printing. Should you not do before?

Comment: @Rajesh `onbeforeprint` is calling before a print dialog appears. So I don't want to close iframe before its printed

Comment: @Rajesh or you mean a line of code if so. It doesn't matter still not working)

Comment: @CodeF0x JS is a single threaded language. So when you receive a browser level popup, execution is stopped. Though not sure, but you should at least try

Comment: The weird thing is this event listener called when I trying to print the main window not an iframe window. So it works only after the main window print event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick for you (a simple trick that worked for me):
you can create your iframe and instead of removing it just dont display it in your UI. so your UI is fine and your print is execute. in next time that you want print another pdf you can check if exist an iframe first remove it and then continue same as before.
so your code will be:

```
export const printPdf = (data: any) => {
  const newBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
  const fileLink = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob)

  const previousIframe=document.getElemenById('print_pdf');
  if(previousIframe){
     previousIframe.remove()
  }

  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.src = fileLink
  iframe.id = 'print_pdf'
  iframe.name = 'print_pdf'
  
  iframe.onload = () => {
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)
    window.frames['print_pdf'].focus()
    window.frames['print_pdf'].print()
    iframe.style.display = "none";
  }
```

This questions is for long time ago, but I write an answer for anybody that will have this question in future because I had this problem for a day before.